Ultrasonic Sensor not receiving echo
I've tried quite a few solutions. I found them online and no rearranging of the code is doing it. I'm simply trying to see if the sensor reads at all, and I keep being thrown this:
warnings.warn(DistanceSensorNoEcho('no echo received')) 

Here is my code in Python 3:
import time
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from gpiozero import Robot
from gpiozero import DistanceSensor
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory
import random

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

ultrasonic = DistanceSensor(echo = 7, trigger = 24, pin_factory = PiGPIOFactory()) 
print(ultrasonic)
  
while True:
    print("in loop")
    print(ultrasonic.distance)

I've checked the wiring over and over again. I've changed pins around a handful of times. I went from BOARD to BCM and back again. I've commented out everything that has nothing to do with the ultrasonic sensor (as this is part of a larger robot). I've written and rewritten the code over again and replaced it with "this code works every time for me just fine!" blocks of code from the internet and still nothing.
I'm getting a delivery of a new sensor tonight, and I'll replace it and update you all if it doesn't work still, but beyond that, I'm at a loss of what on earth to do at this point.
